# Application Insights with Node.js / Express

Tags: node.js, express, azure-application-insights

I've a growing collection of Node.js Express services each has a health check endpoint that is pinged every few seconds.

I've added Azure App Insights and thats capturing data as expected for every request.

My problem is I need to only send/collect data from specific endpoints and for specific actions not every single request. So i really just need to have a single instance of the default client and use that wherever I need to.

Inside my app.ts file I have something like this:

```
import appInsights from "applicationinsights";
.
..
...
appInsights
    .setup(<my app insights key>)
    .start();
.
..
...
const client = appInsights.defaultClient;
```

Any advice or good quality examples?

Comment: App insights could collect data from your application. And how do you like to use it for health check? Did you mean that you wanna only gather metric from health check endpoint while other requests won't be gathered by app insights?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using expressjs, you could just create a separate Middleware that contains the appInsights.  Then add that middleware to the routes you want to track.

i.e.: `app.use('/myroute',appInsightMiddleware, routes)`

Comment: So catching errors (error middleware) i can add AppInsights to my custom error handling as middleware.

Comment: correct.  `app.use(errorHandlerWithAppInsights)`