Using Azure AppInsights in a Nodejs Express Azure WebApp Application
How do I configure Azure AppInsights with all routes to log exceptions and console statements?
This is appInsights.js:
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');

appInsights.setup(process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING)
.setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
.setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
.start();

module.exports = appInsights

routes/index.js:

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { appInsights } = require('../services/appInsights');
const { botService } = require('../services/bot');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/api/messages', async function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("--inside /messages--")
  try {
  //call a method from bot.js
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in /messages:', error);
    appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception: error });
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }


Currently, everything is being logged as "trace" in App Insights and the exceptions are not shown separately even though I've used
appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception: error });
in index.js and I'm also unsure how to use this in bot.js. I've tried importing appInsights again in Bot.js, but that results in duplication of logs. I'm familiar with AWS where I just create a lambda and it has Cloudwatch logs by default and this is my first time working on Azure.

Currently are you able to log other traces (info,warning..etc)..?

@Harshitha, in AppInsights console there are different sections: Trace, Dependancy, Request, Exceptions.
Right now, everything is logged under Trace.  The errors from console.error are logged. I don't see any other info and warnings. My understanding was that if I used trackExceptions exceptions would be logged separately making it easier to debug.

So you want to log traces for all severity level including errors at a time?

Yes, and for all routes. The latter, I think is supposed to be done with the use of AppInsights as a middleware, but I'm not sure how to that. As I said, directly importing AppInsights again in Bot.js duplicates the logs I already have.

What does you mean by duplicates the logs?

I imported appInsights from appInsights.js again in bot.js to test an exception when calling an azure function and the exceptions still aren't being logged separately and the logs of the whole process gets printed twice. I'm not sure if  appInsights is getting initialized again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67197260/application-insights-with-node-js-express
This might give you some context of what I'm trying to do and I'm hoping for a better/detailed solution because I still don't get how to call exceptions from other files.

Did you get a chance to look into this MSDoc

@Matthew Holliday are you looking for this

@SirraSneha yes.

@SirraSneha (Im not able to edit the last comment for some reason) Yes, precisely this. I'd also like exceptions to be implemented for all routes/files. I'm trying to do this with having appinsights as a middleware I'd just like some pointers/examples on how to do this as I've not worked on express and azure before.

I'm able to see logs in exceptions and traces separately.
The exceptions handled in the catch block are displayed in the exception section.
I've added this try catch block code to index.js file
try {
    await someMethod();
    res.status(200).send('Message processed successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in /messages:', error);
    appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception: error });
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }

My index.js file:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const appInsights = require('../services/appInsights'); 
const { someMethod } = require('../services/bot'); 
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('API running at: /api/names, /api/error, /api/dependency');
});
router.get('/api/names', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(['Tony', 'Lisa', 'Michael', 'Ginger', 'Food']);
});
router.get('/api/error', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    throw new Error('This is a test error');
  } catch (error) {

    appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception: error });  
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});
router.post('/api/messages', async function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("--inside /messages--");
  try {
    await someMethod();
    res.status(200).send('Message processed successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in /messages:', error);
    appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception: error });
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
module.exports = router;

My bot.js file:
const appInsights = require('../services/appInsights');
async function someMethod() {
  try {
        console.log("Simulated successful process in bot service");
    return "Success";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in bot service:', error);
    appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception: error });
    throw error;
  }
}
module.exports = {
  someMethod
};

I've added few more methods in appInsights.js
My appInsights.js file
const  appInsights  =  require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup("
process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING")
.setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
.setAutoCollectRequests(true)
.setAutoCollectPerformance(true, true)
.setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
.setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
.setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
.setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
.setSendLiveMetrics(false)
.setDistributedTracingMode(appInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C)
.start();
module.exports  =  appInsights;

My app.js file:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const appInsights = require('./services/appInsights');
app.use(express.json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  appInsights.defaultClient.trackRequest({ name: req.method + ' ' + req.url, url: req.url, time: new Date(), duration: 0, resultCode: res.statusCode, success: true });
  next();
});
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error('Unhandled error:', err);
  appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception: err });
  res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', port);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

Now, for every route, I have the App Insights log traces.




